# How to keep only releases in git history

Tags: git

In my current repository I've got `~80` **commits** and `3` **releases/tags** (`v0.1`, `v0.2`, `v0.3`).

Is there a way to change the repository to only keep the three releases with all the changes between two subsequent releases in only a single commit.
As a result I'd like to have `v0.1 -> one commit -> v0.2 -> one commit -> v0.3`.

For the future I found a way with branches, but I don't know to best change the git history.

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of problem you're trying to solve by doing this? I can tell you that future bug hunts is going to be affected by this, the ability to go back and look at individual commits to see exactly when a bug was introduced might be invaluable. Why do you want to throw that away?

Comment: Try git rebase. you easily cherry pick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rebasing between tagged versions removing other commits on Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681171/rebasing-between-tagged-versions-removing-other-commits-on-git)

Comment: I would advise against this. It will lose valuable history explaining why changes were made helping future developers. If you're looking to reduce the repository size there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easily possible.

Without any fancy rewriting, rebasing, squashing, you can do it thus (assuming your existing local repository is in `$REPOS1` and the path `$REPOS2` does not exist yet:

```
git init $REPOS2

for $TAG in v0.1 v0.2 v0.3 v0.4 ; do
  cd $REPOS1
  git checkout $TAG
  rm -rf $REPOS2/*         # Assuming there are no files/dirs starting with "." except ".git", which we skip
  cp -r * $REPOS2/        
  cd $REPOS2
  git add -A ; git commit -m "$TAG" ; git tag "$TAG"
done
```

This might seem to be naive, but it actually works perfectly since `git` is only considering the *content* (and mode) of files when adding/committing, and it automagically detects if files between the two operations stay identical. It will re-use the existing objects and you will get a perfect "diff" at the end.

In the `rm` and `cp` steps, you want to a) delete everything from `$REPOS2` except the `$REPOS2/.git` tree, and then copy everything from `$REPOS1` to `$REPOS2` except the `$REPOS1/.git` tree. If you do have other files/directories starting with a `.`,  then you need to modify those commands as you see fit (maybe using `find` or `tar --exclude` or whatever you can think of).

If, at the end, you want to stay with this cleaned-up history, then throw away `$REPOS1` and continue with `$REPOS2`. If, though, you want to keep your original history, then merge the two together:

```
cd $REPOS2
git remote add $REPOS1 repos1
git fetch repos1
for $TAG in master v0.1 v0.2 v0.3 v0.4 ; do
  git tag old-$TAG repos1/$TAG
done
git remote del repos1
```

(Assuming you never branched in `$REPOS1`.) After this, `$REPOS2` also will contain all your old history, in tags starting with `old-`. You now can throw `$REPOS1` away.

Comment: Ok, understood, easy and clear approach. I tried with rebase etc.and did not succeed. I'll try tomorrow morning and give a feedback here. Thanks!